# Evaluate the distances between a point and two intervals

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have to evaluate the following sum of distances
$$
\frac{1}{2}(d(y, \mathcal T_1)^2+d(y, \mathcal T_2)^2)\tag{$\star$}
$$
where $y\in\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal T_1=]-\infty, -1]$, $\mathcal T_2=[1, +\infty[$. I know that
\begin{align*}
d(y, \mathcal T_1)^2&=\inf\{|y-x|^2:x\in]-\infty, -1]\}\\
d(y, \mathcal T_2)^2&=\inf\{|y-x|^2:x\in[1, +\infty[\}
\end{align*}
but I cannot evaluate the sum $(\star)$ of such distances.

Can someone help me?

Thank You

Comment: Try a case distinction between $y<-1$, $-1\leq y < 1$, and $1\leq y$.

Comment: If $y<-1$ and $-1\leq y<1$, then $d(y, \mathcal T_1)=0$ and if $1\leq y$, then $d(y, \mathcal T_1)=2$, right?

Comment: I agree with the case $y<-1$. However, try again for the other cases. Which value will $x$ take in these cases?

Comment: Ok with the case $y<-1$. If $-1\leq y<1$, I think that $x=-1$ realizes the smallest distance. Can you give me some other hint? Thank you

Comment: You've got it right now. The same applies also to the case $1\leq y$. All you need to do now is to plug in that value of $x$ and work out the analogue for $d(y,\mathcal{T}_2)$. Can you take it from here?